# Python: 'function' object has no attribute x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello I'm having an issue calling a function on an object in Python.
This is the Method im trying to call

```
def getCenter(self):
    cx = 0
    cy = 0
    for p in self.points:
        cx += p.x
        cy += p.y
    cx /= len(self.points)
    cy /= len(self.points)
    return Point(cx,cy,self.cid)
```

this is the call im trying to make

```
for c in clusters:
    print(c.points,c.cid)
    poi = c.getCenter
    print(poi.x)
```

clusters have a list of points called "points". A point looks like this

```
class Point:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    cluster = -1
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I'm getting the error message 'function' object has no attribute 'x'. I'm calling the getCenter-method on a Cluster which returns a point. And im calling the x attribut on that point. So i dont know why this error is appearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line here:

```
poi = c.getCenter
```

Is not calling the function, it's assigning the function to the name `poi`. You need parenthesis to actually call it:

```
poi = c.getCenter()
```

Comment: Cheers mate, helped me a lot :)